# jquery.nav.js active section highlighted stop working after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Making a single page website, I want the menus to be highlighted depending on what section I am on on the page. I use the jquery.nav.js plugin.

Everything works as needed, until I click on one of the menu links, then the menu section stays on that highlighted link when moving around on the page.

here is the site: http://www.onepixelroom.com/londonrefurb/

the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nav.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav').onePageNav();
});
</script>
```

the nav html:

```
<ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#second" class="smoothScroll">about</a></li>
      <li><span class="bar">|</span></li>
      <li><a href="#fourth" class="smoothScroll">services</a></li>
      <li><span class="bar">|</span></li>
      <li><a href="#sixth" class="smoothScroll">portfolio</a></li>
      <li><span class="bar">|</span></li>
      <li><a href="#eight" class="smoothScroll">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and the CSS:

```
#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 80px;
    width: 325px;
    margin: auto;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    color: #5B5B5B;
}
/*
color:#49E2D6;
*/

#nav .current a {
    color: #40E4F2;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color:#40E4F2;
}
#nav li {
float: left;
}
#nav  a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs this, I fixed this by adding the class ".current" to each  and adding to the script

JavaScript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nav').onePageNav({
    currentClass: 'current',
    scrollOffset: 0
  });
});

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#second" class="current">about</a></li>
  <li><span class="bar">|</span></li>
  <li><a href="#fourth" class="current">services</a></li>
  <li><span class="bar">|</span></li>
  <li><a href="#sixth" class="current">portfolio</a></li>
  <li><span class="bar">|</span></li>
  <li><a href="#eight" class="current">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please correct me if I made a mistake.